# Call a Function in createbottomtabsnavigator

Tags: react-native, tabs, bottomnavigationview, tabnavigator

I am using react native and i want to call a function in tabs

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(  
    {  
      Home:{  
        screen:CustomMapView,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Home',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Image source = {require("../../Images/react-logo.png")} style={{width : 30 , height:30}}/> 
          )  
        }  
      }, Profile11:{  
        screen:Profile11,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Profile11',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <Image source = {require("../../Images/react-logo.png")} style={{width : 30 , height:30}}/> 
          )  
        }  
      },  
      Profile: {  
        screen:ProfileScreen,  
        navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              // <Icon name="ios-person" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
            <Image source = {require("../../Images/react-logo.png")} style={{width : 30 , height:30}}/> 
          )  
        }  
      },  
    },  
    {  
      initialRouteName: "Home"  
    },  
);
```

As i am using above i want to set some contions on tabs like home if condition true run set CustomMapView as the screen if condition false any other screen will set like CustomMapView.js

how can i do this

Comment: Are you trying to call a function on tab press or want to set a condition depending on which the page will be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example if you want to set a condition for rendering page:

```
const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeTab ,
    Settings: SettingsTab ,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          return (
            <Image
              source={ require('./assets/home.png') }
              style={{ width: 20, height: 20, }} />
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <Image
              source={ require('./assets/settings.png') }
              style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
          );
        }
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#FF6F00',
      inactiveTintColor: '#263238',
    },
  });
```

And if you want to call a method on tab press, then refer this example :

```
Profile: {  
    screen:ProfileScreen,  
    navigationOptions:{  
      tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
          // <Icon name="ios-person" color={tintColor} size={25}/>  
        <Image source = {require("../../Images/react-logo.png")} style={{width : 30 , height:30}}/> 
      ),
      tabBarOnPress: () => { this.openGallery() }  
    }  
  },
```

Comment: Hi, I want to run a function. in that function there must be conditions like if user login then go to this screen otherwise to another screen. Sandip above code is not working. So please tell how can i call a function. as you wrote above.

Comment: For calling a function on tab press you can use 'tabBarOnPress'. Refer this Link : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress

Comment: @user10949835      lets assume   const[login,setLogin] = useState(false)
   component={login===false?StackScreen_Profile:EmptyComponent} like this you can go to different screens